# Using Aforge.net or C# to get or set camera properties ( e.g. exposure time)

Tags: c#, api, camera, aforge

I'm currently looking for some libraries `.dll` that allow me to interfere with the web camera to set or get the camera parameters, although the Microsoft Lifecam (the webcam) already provided an API preinstalled, I want to write the code the set these properties in my own windows form program. Appreciate any idea!

Using Aforge.net or C# to get or set camera properties ( e.g. exposure time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea, by using the library (dll) of AForge, you can do that.
Here I put a snippet of the code for setting the exposure value.

You might get an example project here:
[CameraPrefs - example](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/is-it-possible-to-save-auto-focus-auto-color/e6b812e3-5e52-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

```
public VideoCaptureDevice source;
private IAMCameraControl cameraControls;

...

// Match specified camera name to device
FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
for (int i = 0, n = videoDevices.Count; i < n; i++)
{
    if (name == videoDevices[i].Name)
    {
        moniker = videoDevices[i].MonikerString;
        break;
    }
}

source = new VideoCaptureDevice(moniker);
cameraControls = (IAMCameraControl)source.SourceObject;

cameraControls.Set(CameraControlProperty.Exposure, -11, CameraControlFlags.Manual);
```

I hope this might help others as well; in case if you already figure out the way to do this. =)

Comment: Not all camera's support retrieval of such data, just FYI.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 Yes, I got it already a month ago, thanks for your contribution to the stack overflow society.